# Multiple datasets grouping with react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to replicate a search field using old jQuery typeahead with react-bootstrap-typeahead. It queries uses multiple async data sources, and display the result grouped by the return of such sources.

[image: multiple sources displayed]

For instance, as seen on the image, by typing the letter "b" it queries an address database as well as the previously searched values by user (saved on React store) and display results grouped by each database. If a result is empty for a given database, it is not shown, as the next example:

[image: single source displayed]

According to [this closed issue on the project](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/603) it is possible to query multiple databases making multiple queries on the `onSearch` function. But is it possible to group the results like on the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to group the search results in the way you describe. You can use the `renderMenu` prop to group the results by data source and render a menu header to denote each source.

Here's an adaptation from the [live examples](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#rendering):

```js
const renderMenu = (results, menuProps, props) => {
  let index = 0;

  // Group the results by the "region" key in each option.
  const regions = groupBy(results, 'region');
  const items = Object.keys(regions)
    .sort()
    .map((region) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={region}>
          {index !== 0 && <Menu.Divider />}
          <Menu.Header>{region}</Menu.Header>
          {regions[region].map((option) => {
            const item = (
              <MenuItem key={option.label} option={option} position={index}>
                <Highlighter search={props.text}>{option.label}</Highlighter>
              </MenuItem>
            );

            index += 1;
            return item;
          })}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });

  return <Menu {...menuProps}>{items}</Menu>;
};

const GroupedResults = () => {
  return (
    <Typeahead
      id="grouped-results"
      options={options}
      placeholder="Choose a state..."
      renderMenu={renderMenu}
    />
  );
};
```

Here's the [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-8uyy1v).

As far as the data source is concerned, note that the typeahead component is essentially agnostic about that; it is simply filtering the array passed into the `options` prop, which can come from anywhere, or even multiple places.

Comment: just created a new question, thought about commenting here but it seemed to me that it would be more helpful for future readers if I posted it as a separate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128554/queries-with-minlength-equal-to-zero

Thanks a lot!