# Queries with minLength equal to zero

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

So I am creating this search component based on react-bootstrap-typeahead with multiple sources [migrating from old jQuery based typeahead as mentioned in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990255/multiple-datasets-grouping-with-react-bootstrap-typeahead). One of the sources is a list of previously searched values, queried on React store.

However the current search component has a special case: if *nothing* is typed on the search bar (i.e. the user focus the input), it displays a list of the previously searched values:

[image: previously searched items with empty input]

I have tried replicating that behavior by setting `minLength={0}` and handling it in the `handleSearch` function (testing if `query === ''`), however the function is not called when the input is empty:

[image: type to search]

Is it possible to run the `handleSearch` function with an empty input? Or should I simply do it manually attach an event to the `onFocus` and display the content manually when the input is empty and hiding it `onBlur` and when the input is not empty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not totally sure how your app is structured, but it sounds like the previous results are immediately available from the store when the component renders. You should set those as the initial values passed to `options`, then as the user fetches more results, you'll need to concatenate the options and group them when you render the menu. You may need to turn off the typeahead's cache and handle any query caching yourself.

Comment: Indeed that is the case. So I did it here a initial `options` filling when the component is mounted, then again on `onInputChange`, testing if `text` is empty. Doing so it was not necessary to change the cache. Thanks again ericgio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I did in the end was, inside of the component (assume that the results that you want to show are received as `props.searchHistory`, and you want to display them grouped as `previousResults`):

```js
const [isEmptySearchInitialized, setIsEmptySearchInitialized] = useState(false);

const setEmptySearchResults = () => {
    const { searchHistory } = props;
    const previousResults = searchHistory;
    const concatenatedPreviousResults = { previousResults };
    setOptions(previousResults);
    setGroupedSearchData(concatenatedPreviousResults);
    setIsEmptySearchInitialized(true);
};

const handleInputChange = (text, event) => {
    // resets to previously search items when user erases the text input
    if (text === '') {
        setEmptySearchResults();
    }
};

if (!isEmptySearchInitialized) {
    setEmptySearchResults();
}

// (...)

return (
    <AsyncTypeahead
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        // (...)
    />
);
```

Doing so it sets the `options` with the `previousResults`, displaying them as initial options when the user clicks on the input, and sets it again when the user erases the search options.

[image: showing options with empty text]